# Line-staging stopped working at Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide

My Visual Studio 2022 stopped showing option to choose each line to stage. It used to do so, but recent updates changed that and I can't find how to renable that.

How can I get this working again?

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.2

From [this Microsoft reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/line-staging-interactive-staging/):

> If you need to switch off this new feature, you can use CTRL+Q, type “preview” and open the preview features pane. Scroll to “Enable line-staging support” and toggle the checkbox.

In my case, see print below, this option is not shown.

[image: Current preview features panel]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Toggle the "[Show Staging Controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4sXh.png)" button in the top right of your diff viewer.

Comment: Sometimes the simple solution is not readly seen

Comment: There is no 'show staging controls' button any more, in 17.6.2.

Comment: revised comment (couldn't edit after 5 minutes - thanks stackoverflow): There is no 'show staging controls' button any more, in 17.6.2., for some files. I have not yet discovered why the button is there for some files with multiple changes and not for others.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes even "Show staging controls" doesn't work. In fact it can work in one part of a file but not in another! I found that switching between diff modes sometimes brings up the staging controls: In the diff window, press the gear icon drop-down arrow in the top right corner and select "right file only". Then line-staging controls come up.